# Executing stored procedure from a bat file from Task Scheduler - does not run in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, windows-task-scheduler

We migrated to a new Windows Server 2019 Data Center and need to execute a stored procedure every night. We're also using SQL Server version 15.0.2080.9

We were successfully doing this on the old server for many years. If I double click on the bat file everything runs as expected but when this bat file is run from Task Scheduler nothing happens from Task Scheduler.

Here's the bat file:

sqlcmd -E -S MyServer -d MyDatabase -Q "exec [dbo].[spzTestLog_insert]"

The task runs under a Windows Server administrator user account which is also assigned as sa in SQL Server.

Running from a SQL Job is not an option.  I have over 20 scripts that have to be executed in sequence, most are Python scripts processing GIS data in another server and intermittently I have to run SQL scripts importing and processing data from the GIS server.

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: If you selected "Run whether user is logged on or not" then the user account also need "logon as a batch job" permissions in Local Security Policy

Comment: Is the new Windows Server 2019 Data Center in the same Active Directory/Kerberos realm as the old server, and especially the server from which the Task Scheduler item is being executed?

Comment: Are you capturing the output from sqlcmd.  You can write it to a file with `-o "c:\temp\sqlcmd.log"`